# Collectionview segue View is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view and each cell links to a detailed view controller. This used to work fine but now when I click on a cell I get the following error

Attempt to present "Detailed view" on "Collection View" whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

How can the 'didSelectItemAtIndexPath' be firing to instigate the segue if the view is not in the window hierarchy? This is the code to present the detail views. All the switch cases display the println statement when cells are clicked but none present the detail view.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

switch (indexPath.item) {
case 0:
  performSegueWithIdentifier("showMonth", sender: self)
  println("cell pressed")
  break;

default:
  break;
}

}
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Yes, please provide the relevants parts code and/or details of your storyboard.

Comment: Also, if this used to work fine an now doesn't, you may want to check the latest revision where it does and check any changes made in the next revision.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the code called to display the detail view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved the issue. I have no idea why it affected the view hierarchy but it was iAds that was causing the issue. I commented out the line of code

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

and it's now working fine again.